# segfault after linking with custom libc

Tags: linux, gcc, build, glibc

I'm trying to compile glibc with debug symbols and use it for small application. So I downloaded and glibc, compiled without problems, installed in /custobuilds and now I'm compiling my own app:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -g -Wall -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/custobuilds/lib/ld-2.27.so   -o CMakeFiles/annotation.dir/annotation.o -c annotation.cpp
/usr/bin/c++ -g -Wall -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/custobuilds/lib/ld-2.27.so   CMakeFiles/annotation.dir/annotation.o /custobuilds/lib/crt1.o /custobuilds/lib/crti.o  -o annotation  -L/custobuilds/lib -rdynamic -lc -Wl,-rpath,/custobuilds/lib
```

Things get linked correctly:

```
zhani@zhani-Aspire-E1-571G:~/Thesis/test/build$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./annotation 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe8558f000)
libc.so.6 => /custobuilds/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f73e02c2000)
/custobuilds/lib/ld-2.27.so (0x00007f73e0677000)
```

In source I also have included correct files, only

```
#include "/custobuilds/include/stdio.h"
```

And I only have one scanf()/printf() there. I have checked with gdb, it crashes before reaching main()

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get linked correctly

No, it doesn't: you are missing `crtn.o`, and the order of objects on the link line generally should be:

```
crt1.o crti.o main.o -lc crtn.o
```